# Zustand Middleware that modifies state automatically

Tags: typescript, middleware, zustand

I have a zustand store and want to create a middleware that automatically stores the current date whenever I call `set()`.

I think this could be done manually like so:

```
// store
create((set) => ({
  counter: 1,
  lastModifiedAt: null,
  increaseCounter: () =>
    set((s) => ({
      ...prev,
      lastModifiedAt: Date.now(), // <-- how to automate this using a middleware?
      counter: s.counter + 1
    })),
}));
```

Because `lastModifiedAt` should be set whenever the state changes, I think a middleware would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Answering in TypeScript, but it can be easily transformed to vanilla JS. Having these basic types for starters

```
interface HasLastModified {
  lastModifiedAt?: number;
}

interface StoreState{
  count: number;
}

interface StoreActions {
  increaseCounter: (by: number) => void;
}

type Store = StoreState & StoreActions;
```

you now have at least two options:

### Option 1: having the `lastModifiedAt` property as a part of store state

Based on [this article](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/typescript#middleware-that-doesn%27t-change-the-store-type) in zustand documentation. This is a case, that you described in your question.

```
import { create, StateCreator, StoreMutatorIdentifier } from "zustand";
import { HasLastModified, Store } from "./AutoLastModifiedTypes";

type AutoLastModifiedDate = <
  T extends HasLastModified,
  Mps extends [StoreMutatorIdentifier, unknown][] = [],
  Mcs extends [StoreMutatorIdentifier, unknown][] = []
>(
  stateCreator: StateCreator<T, Mps, Mcs>
) => StateCreator<T, Mps, Mcs>;

type AutoLastModifiedDateImpl = <T extends HasLastModified>(
  stateCreator: StateCreator<T, [], []>
) => StateCreator<T, [], []>;

type SetterFn<T> = (state: T) => T | Partial<T>;

const impl: AutoLastModifiedDateImpl = (stateCreator) => (set, get, store) => {
  const newSet: typeof set = function (...args) {
    let newState = args[0];

    if (isSetterFunction(newState)) {
      newState = newState(get());
    }

    const newResult = { ...newState, lastModifiedAt: Date.now() };
    set(newResult, args[1]);
  };

  store.setState = newSet;
  return stateCreator(newSet, get, store);
};

const isSetterFunction = function <T>(setter: T | Partial<T> | SetterFn<T>): setter is SetterFn<T> {
  return (setter as SetterFn<T>).apply !== undefined;
};

export const autoLastModifiedDate = impl as AutoLastModifiedDate;

//--
type StoreWithLastModified = Store & HasLastModified;
const stateCreator: StateCreator<StoreWithLastModified, [], []> = (set) => ({
  count: 0,
  lastModifiedAt: undefined,
  increaseCounter: (by: number) => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + by }))
});
const useStore = create<StoreWithLastModified>()(autoLastModifiedDate(stateCreator));

export default useStore;
```

### Option 2: having the `lastModifiedAt` property on the store itself

Based on [this article](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/typescript#middleware-that-changes-the-store-type) in zustand documentation. Here we store the `lastModifiedAt` property in some kind of *metadata* or *stats* object, which lies directly in the store. Note that keeping the `lastModifiedAt` property directly on the store without the encapsulating `meta` object did not work. Although the property was updated, no changes were ever visible to *"outside consumers"*.

```
import { create, Mutate, StateCreator, StoreApi, StoreMutatorIdentifier } from "zustand";
import { HasLastModified, Store } from "./AutoLastModifiedTypes";

type Write<T extends object, U extends object> = Omit<T, keyof U> & U;
type Cast<T, U> = T extends U ? T : U;

declare module "zustand" {
  interface StoreMutators<S, A> {
    autoLastModifiedDate: Write<Cast<S, object>, { meta: HasLastModified }>;
  }
}

type AutoLastModifiedDate = <
  T,
  Mps extends [StoreMutatorIdentifier, unknown][] = [],
  Mcs extends [StoreMutatorIdentifier, unknown][] = []
>(
  stateCreator: StateCreator<T, [...Mps, ["autoLastModifiedDate", HasLastModified]], Mcs>,
  initialValue?: HasLastModified
) => StateCreator<T, Mps, [["autoLastModifiedDate", HasLastModified], ...Mcs]>;

type AutoLastModifiedDateImpl = <T>(
  stateCreator: StateCreator<T, [], []>,
  initialValue?: HasLastModified
) => StateCreator<T, [], []>;

const impl: AutoLastModifiedDateImpl = (stateCreator, initialValue) => (set, get, _store) => {
  type T = ReturnType<typeof stateCreator>;
  const store = _store as Mutate<StoreApi<T>, [["autoLastModifiedDate", HasLastModified]]>;
  store.meta = initialValue || {};

  const newSet: typeof set = function (...args) {
    store.meta.lastModifiedAt = Date.now();
    set(...args);
  };

  store.setState = newSet;
  return stateCreator(newSet, get, _store);
};

export const autoLastModifiedDate = impl as AutoLastModifiedDate;

//--
const stateCreator: StateCreator<Store, [], []> = (set) => ({
  count: 0,
  increaseCounter: (by: number) => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + by }))
});
const useStore = create<Store>()(autoLastModifiedDate(stateCreator));
useStore.subscribe(() => console.log(`Type store change detected. ${useStore.meta.lastModifiedAt || " not yet"}`));
export default useStore;
```

### Using stores

A component using these stores could then look something like this

```
import useTypeStore from "./AutoLastModifiedTypeStore";
import useStateStore from "./AutoLastModifiedStateStore";

const AutoLastModifiedCounter = () => {
  const increaseTypeStoreCounter = useTypeStore((state) => state.increaseCounter);
  const typeStoreCount = useTypeStore((state) => state.count);
  const typeStorelastModifiedAt = useTypeStore.meta.lastModifiedAt;

  const increaseStateStoreCounter = useStateStore((state) => state.increaseCounter);
  const stateStoreCount = useStateStore((state) => state.count);
  const stateStoreLastModifiedAt = useStateStore((state) => state.lastModifiedAt);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Type store. Count = {typeStoreCount}, last modified at = {typeStorelastModifiedAt}
        <button onClick={() => increaseTypeStoreCounter(1)}>Increment Type Store</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        State store. Count = {stateStoreCount}, last modified at = {stateStoreLastModifiedAt}
        <button onClick={() => increaseStateStoreCounter(1)}>Increment State Store</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoLastModifiedCounter;
```